# Html marquee with foreach

Tags: c#, html, marquee

I have a Html Code as following

```
 <%var list = ViewData["list"] as IList<Entity>;%>
<html>
<div>

<%foreach(var detail in list){ %>
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" align ="center"><a href ="">
<%=detail.EventName%></a></marquee>

<%}%>
</div>
</html>
```

Is not executed well cause of foreach loop 
can you please suggest me that how should I use marquee that my format is not looks bad ?

Comment: is not executed well is not very informative. What is the problem?

Comment: 1 marquee looks bad on a page, but multiple must look real bad! You also have a tags with no link?

Comment: Problem is that my div size extended cause for foreach loop .i will add link latter according to my requirement.

Comment: Could you rephrase that? It sounds like the problem is that if you have more lines on the screen, they take up more space.

Comment: yes.its something like that

Comment: OK, and what kind of solution do expect? How to display fewer lines?

Comment: No,Show moving text with more lines without loosing my html page format.

Comment: Still not clear. You mean you want all the lines in one marquee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964491/is-it-acceptable-to-use-the-marquee-element-in-html). Marquee has been deprecated by the W3C but there area few alternatives listed in the answer.  Maybe try explaining what you're trying to do. It's quite possible you don't actually need a marquee.