# Increasing opacity on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opacity

When I scroll I would like the text to appear the same way as on the picture, with growing opacity. Could you help me with this?

[image: Opacity effect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two `<div>`'s with a background gradient to accomplish this effect.

Here are two JSFiddles that show what I mean:

-[Example w/ Code](http://jsfiddle.net/SplashHero/dwz2194t/)

-[Fullscreen Result](http://jsfiddle.net/SplashHero/dwz2194t/embedded/result/)

Comment: Consider using the [stack snippet tool](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: @apaul34208 I could, but I prefer JSFiddle.

Comment: For most things I prefer jsFiddle as well, but jsFiddle goes down occasionally so it is a good idea to include the code in the answer as well.

Comment: @apaul34208 I actually haven't thought of that before... It is good advice and I will most definitely use it in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set 2 image ( on top and on bottom ) over text with opacity with position fixed or absolute, and when scroll text images will be over bottom text and over top text :)
Hope i help you!! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/7ox2rmmc/) code, a sample like your code:

```
body {
    height: 500px;
}
.Top {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://afkarco.ir/images/Bottom.png);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}

marquee {
    margin: 100px 0;
    height: 500px;
}

.Bottom {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://afkarco.ir/images/Top.png);
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/7ox2rmmc/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3964491/1947286

Comment: @apaul34208 I use marquee just for a demonstration purpose...

Comment: Honestly that was the first time I've seen the marquee tag used. Just thought it would be worth noting that it isn't a good idea to use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the site in your image is using stacked .png -s to create the effect. If you don't want to use images, you could fake it using a cover div with a box-shadow:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  padding: 20px 50px
}
.pCover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 40px #fff inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="pCover"></div>
<p>
  Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas,
  imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. Qui animated corpse, cricket bat max brucks terribilem incessu zomby. The voodoo sacerdos flesh eater, suscitat mortuos comedere carnem virus. Zonbi tattered for solum
  oculi eorum defunctis go lum cerebro. Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead. Cum horribilem walking dead resurgere de crazed sepulcris creaturis, zombie sicut de grave feeding iride et serpens. Pestilentia,
  shaun ofthe dead scythe animated corpses ipsa screams. Pestilentia est plague haec decaying ambulabat mortuos. Sicut zeder apathetic malus voodoo. Aenean a dolor plan et terror soulless vulnerum contagium accedunt, mortui iam vivam unlife. Qui tardius
  moveri, brid eof reanimator sed in magna copia sint terribiles undeath legionis. Alii missing oculis aliorum sicut serpere crabs nostram. Putridi braindead odores kill and infect, aere implent left four dead. Lucio fulci tremor est dark vivos magna.
  Expansis creepy arm yof darkness ulnis witchcraft missing carnem armis Kirkman Moore and Adlard caeruleum in locis. Romero morbo Congress amarus in auras. Nihil horum sagittis tincidunt, zombie slack-jawed gelida survival portenta. The unleashed virus
  est, et iam zombie mortui ambulabunt super terram. Souless mortuum glassy-eyed oculos attonitos indifferent back zom bieapoc alypse. An hoc dead snow braaaiiiins sociopathic incipere Clairvius Narcisse, an ante? Is bello mundi z? In Craven omni memoria
  patriae zombieland clairvius narcisse religionis sunt diri undead historiarum. Golums, zombies unrelenting et Raimi fascinati beheading. Maleficia! Vel cemetery man a modern bursting eyeballs perhsaps morbi. A terrenti flesh contagium. Forsitan deadgurl
  illud corpse Apocalypsi, vel staggering malum zomby poenae chainsaw zombi horrifying fecimus burial ground. Indeflexus shotgun coup de poudre monstra per plateas currere. Fit de decay nostra carne undead. Poenitentiam violent zom biehig hway agite RE:dead
  pœnitentiam! Vivens mortua sunt apud nos night of the living dead. Whyt zomby Ut fames after death cerebro virus enim carnis grusome, viscera et organa viventium. Sicut spargit virus ad impetum, qui supersumus flesh eating. Avium, brains guts, ghouls,
  unholy canum, fugere ferae et infecti horrenda monstra. Videmus twenty-eight deformis pale, horrenda daemonum. Panduntur brains portae rotting inferi. Finis accedens walking deadsentio terrore perterritus et twen tee ate daze leighter taedium wal kingdead.
  The horror, monstra epidemic significant finem. Terror brains sit unum viral superesse undead sentit, ut caro eaters maggots, caule nobis.
</p>
```