# Behavior of <marquee> tag in HTML (Like cast in the end of film)

Tags: javascript, html

See

```html
<marquee>This is basic example of marquee</marquee>
```

I need see word "this" on the right side of screen when it disappear from the left.

Thank you in advance!

This is basic example of marquee

Comment: You probably should add a snippet or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead of an off-site resource.

Comment: You must not use `marquee` because it is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964491/is-the-marquee-html-element-supported-by-all-browsers-yet)

Comment: probably you need a jquarry plugin try this one , [jquarry-plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Text-Scrolling-Plugin-for-jQuery-Marquee/) . check out "Overwrite the default options with following" example.

Comment: @Ahmed, `<marquee>`  can't be deprecated, it has never been part of any specification. Anyway, +1 to your comment.